# Tell if java application is running with nt authority/system privilege

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to get the username on Windows

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
    }
}
```

It works with normal users, but when I do it with `system` account,

[image]

The value was different from the output of `whoami` command

Any ideas? I need to get the correct name with Java, and it's best without dependency jars

P.S I'm running CMD on a Windows 2008 R2 box

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.name")` is getting the environment properties. If you list all environment variables in Java then you will see this is the value Java has inherret in the shell script on start up. To get the real user you would need to integrate with Windows DLL to  get the logged user.